# Error in LINQ to SQL: specified cast is not valid

Tags: sql, linq

Hi I am trying to learn LINQ, and in LINQ to SQL I have got following exception:
This is a sample code from Linq In Action by Manning publications.
Whats wrong?

```
        DataContext db = new DataContext("E:\\Mahesh\\TempFolder\\DB\\NORTHWND.MDF");

        var contacts =
            from contact in db.GetTable<Contact>()
            where contact.City == "Paris"
            select contact;

        foreach (Contact aContact in contacts)
            Console.WriteLine("Bonjour " + aContact.Name);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

[Table(Name = "Customers")]
class Contact
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "ContactName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Error]

Exception details:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
HResult=-2147467262
Message=Specified cast is not valid.
Source=System.Data
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at Read_Contact(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at LinqDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\MAHESH\Desktop\TechNode\C#\MyTechDos\LinqDemo\LinqDemo\Program.cs:line 51
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Comment: What data type is `contact.City`?  Are you sure it is a `string`?

Comment: @jonnyGold in db contact.City is nvarchar, its Northwind db's Customers table

Comment: @TimSchmelter an image is worth hundred words ;p but code added ;p

Comment: Now while adding more of code SF says: Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly. now whats this????

Comment: View Detail! View Detail! Tell us explicitly what the inner exception is.

Comment: @Totero Exception details added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If my memory serves, the Customers table in Northwind does not have CustomerID as int (I think its NVARCHAR). If you wrote the Contact class manually, instead of have LINQ to SQL generate it, make sure that the types on your class match the types in the database table

EDIT: From this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399575(v=vs.90).aspx am inclined to think that the CustomerID field is not INT but NVARCHAR (or NCHAR for that matter)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when i tried to use **Linq to Sql**. Since my stored procedures used temp tables (Linq to Sql tool doesn't create classes for temp tables).So i had to create my own custom class. The same exception occured.

> StackTrace:
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
>      at Read_Contact(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()

This error occurred because i was trying to cast my **small int** DB type variable to **int** C# variable. In case anyone else goes through the same please refer the official Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) for the DB type to C# type mappings.

Note: If you have a Specified Cast not valid issue then make sure your data types are correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Holy Cow... this was a killer for me.**

Actually this was a SQL Collation problem for me, because i had a field in LINQ-to-SQL called `Dataarea`, but in my SQL View this field was called `DataArea`.  The Upper Cased A in Area was the problem.

Normally the SQL is NOT case sensitive for field-names, but if your SQL collation is DanishNorwegian, then this does work, and i get the "specified cast is not valid".

**Strange error.**

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after importing table to model, I changed one of the variable's datatype in DB but didn't make that change in model. It's better to delete your table from models and regenerate it.